# Determine input source to Java program

Tags: java, windows, autohotkey

I have an AutoHotKey script that sends keystrokes to a running Java program on my computer. How can the Java program tell that the keystrokes came from this specific script? I would imagine it has to do with Java Runtime and Process APIs.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? Why do you believe that discovering this information were part if the solution?

Comment: The Java program must behave a certain way only if it receives keystrokes from a specific source (in this case, the AutoHotKey script).

Comment: Are you trying to detect AutoHotkey bot?

Comment: This is not possible. AutoHotkey uses system services to inject input. Those system services do not record the source. The only thing you can determine is, whether input was generated by a driver representing a hardware device, or through software (see [KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/ns-winuser-tagkbdllhookstruct)). This still sounds like an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info).

Answer (score 0):

There is no native way for Java to tell if the click has come from external source unless the external source notify the recipient application of itself through some hidden input.

Java runs in a virtual machine and the underlying platform is exposed in a limited way compared to native language as C / C++

If a robot/macro/script outside of the JVM is using lets say java REST API or SOAP it can write a header , or something different to report itself to the recipient program. If you have a desktop client you can do something similar by setting a hidden field or some other similar mechanism.